# How to simulate the top site message bar that StackOverflow uses in Rails for the flash[:notice] and flash[:error] messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css

I want to render my Rails flash[:notice] and flash[:error] messages in a bar at the top of the screen, similar to the message bar that StackOverflow uses when you get a new badge etc.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this elegantly?  Extra credit to make it slide in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The railscasts has a screencast regarding site-wide announcements. All that is left - some javascript to create slide-in/slide-out effects.

Here's the link to the screencast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/103-site-wide-announcements